# removeEldestEntry

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap

How can I override `removeEldestEntry` method to saving eldest entry to file with help of `FileOutputStream`, `DataOutputStream` and `writeObject()`. Code.

Here's example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class level1 {
private static final int max_cache = 50;
private Map cache = new LinkedHashMap(max_cache, .75F, true) {
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
        return size() > max_cache;
    }
};


public level1() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 52; i++) {
        String string = String.valueOf(i);
        cache.put(string, string);
        System.out.println("\rCache size = " + cache.size() +
                           "\tRecent value = " + i + " \tLast value = " +
                           cache.get(string) + "\tValues in cache=" +
                           cache.values());

    }
```

Comment: Common code style convention would be to have MAX_CACHE written in all-caps as it is a static final / constant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is almost complete:

```
private Map cache = new LinkedHashMap(max_cache, .75F, true) {
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
       // Pseudo-Code 
       if(this.size() > MAX_CACHE_SIZE){
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
           ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

           oos.writeObject(eldest.getValue());
           return true;
       } finally {
           oos.close();
           fos.close();
       }

       return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Exceptions not handled java.io.FileNltFoundException

Comment: That's what I mentioned with `Pseudo-Code`. Looks like Sourcecode, but does not include bloated Exceptionhandling ...

Comment: incorrect to invoke super.removeEldestEntry(eldest) as its implementation in super always returns false.

Comment: @Avishay_ is right. I edited the example to make more sense in respect to what the OP had originally (some kind of max cache size)

Answer (score 1):

- Call `super.removeEldestEntry`
- If an item was removed open a OutputStream
- Write out the object
- Return the boolean from the super call.

Comment: As a comment in the accepted answer rightfully points out, this is incorrect since `super.removeEldestEntry` will *always* return `false`.